# removing geocode marker after onclick

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am using google maps- directions and geocoding. The geocode places a marker when the page loads. Is it possible to have this marker removed when a user clicks the submit button? I asked earlier and somebody suggested using:

marker.setMap(null);

but I'm not too sure where to place that bit of code

Here is the code:

```
var address = document.getElementById("address").textContent.replace(/\n/g, " ");
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, 
function(results, status) 
{
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  }
  else
   {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});




var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
var request = {
    origin: from, 
    destination: to,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
document.getElementById("map").style.width = "70%";
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: would you mind explaining some of the code that I entered?

1. var markersArray = [];

2. markersArray.push(marker);

3. if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove google geocode on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754407/how-to-remove-google-geocode-on-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the submit button?

```
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="marker.setMap(null);" />
```

This is assuming `marker.setMap(null);` works, of course.

Comment: You must make `marker` a global variable. Also, check out http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#RemovingOverlays.

Comment: thanks for the documentation... that helped me out, but would you mind explaining some of the code that I entered?

1. var markersArray = [];

2. markersArray.push(marker);

3. if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }

Comment: I'm confused. What do you need me to explain? 1 creates an empty array. 2 pushes the marker into the array. 3 will do the following if you have previously defined `markersArray`, which you have if you place those lines in order: it iterates the array, going through every marker (in your case, there's just one), runs `marker.setMap(null)` for each marker; then it remover every marker from `markersArray`.

Comment: This of course means that, if you run 1-2-3 in sequence, that that code will effectively do nothing except for running `setMap(null)` for `marker`.